# Google geocode API doesn't recognise some zipcodes

Tags: google-maps, google-api, geolocation

I am using google geocode+geolocation APIs for finding places and calculating distances between them.

There are some zip codes which actually exist when we search them on Google but google APIs are unable to locate them.

Here is one in the link: [01703](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=01703)

Response is

```
{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

How can I overcome this issue (with Google API) or is there a way to contact  google support directly? Or if there is any other service which has better results?

Please help me to solve this. Waiting for response. Thanks

Comment: Append "USA" to the URL (or whatever your country of interest is)

Answer (score 0):

The Google maps api reads directly from Google maps itself.  If there is data missing then it can be added [Report an error on the map](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088?hl=en)

If it is on the map and just not in the API then they may be in the process of approving the change.

Beyond that you could report it as a bug [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/558483)  or try to contact the [support team](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/support#contact_maps_support)

Normally there isnt much you can do if there is no data in the api for your request there is no data.  For the most part Google services are free "*you get what you pay for*".

Comment: Thank You so much for replying. Is there any other service which I can use in place of google API?

Comment: Your going to have to try to Google for that Stack cant recommend services we are just here to help you fix what your working on.

Answer (score 0):

I am a developer at [SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com), and have worked a lot with our [US ZIP Code API](https://smartystreets.com/products/apis/us-zipcode-api). I ran the ZIP Code `01703` through it, and got back the geocodes no problem. You can try it out for free if you're interested.